# PostgreSQL: Show the code behind TYPE

Tags: postgresql, types

Imagine I've created a TYPE like this

```
CREATE TYPE test_type AS ( col1 bigint, col2 varchar(100), col3 integer, col4 numeric )
```

The question is: how do I see what stands behind the name of a type `test_type` ?

I can do `\dT` and `\dT+`, but it's not giving me what I need (column datatypes of a type and their number).

Why do I need this? Imagine somebody's created a `TYPE` in the past and you are in need of creating a function that returns a `SETOF`, but it (the type you need to return) might have already been implemented - so following the **DRY principle** you wouldn't really like to make something that's already there.

Comment: As you are using `psql`, you can use `\d test_type` to get the columns defined for the type. Any GUI client should show the full SQL statement.

Comment: Thanks for the valid answer. I'm not using GUI clients though.

Comment: As I said: `\d test_type` will show those attributes

Comment: And I've already thanked you for the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see what attribute names and data types a composite type contains simply use

```
\d name_of_a_type
```

It also implies that the name of a `TYPE` must be distinct from name of any existing type, domain or table in the same schema.

This is because one pair (attribute name, data type) used inside `CREATE TYPE` statement is (according to [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtype.html))

> **CREATE TYPE**
>
> [...] **essentially the same as the row type of a table**, but using CREATE TYPE
> avoids the need to create an actual table when all that is wanted is
> to define a type. A stand-alone composite type is useful as the
> argument or return type of a function.

Answer (score 0):

A quick way to `see what stands behind the name of a type`:

```
SELECT (NULL::name_of_composite_type).*;
```

Works in *any* client, because it's just SQL. Your client returns names and types filled with `NULL` values - just like a row from a table.

Comment: A simple select like this would not return datatypes for columns, but will present (as you've already said) a row filled with nulls.